# CodeMirror Initialization Value Not Working

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Why does the value property "some code" not showing up when I load this page?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/codemirror-5.47.0/lib/codemirror.css">
  <script src="lib/codemirror-5.47.0/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/codemirror-5.47.0/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/codemirror-5.47.0/mode/powershell//powershell.js"></script>

  <title>Code Mirror</title>

</head>


<body>
  <h1>Hello Code Mirror</h1>

  Code Mirror <a href="https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html">Documenation</a>

  </br>

  <textarea id='jsTxtArea'></textarea>

</body>



<script>
  var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('jsTxtArea'), {
    value: "some code",
    lineNumbers:true,
    mode:"javascript"

});
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value from the textarea, like so:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('jsTxtArea');
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea , {
    value: textarea.innerHtml,
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: 'javascript'
});
```

Or, if you want to set the value within the JavaScript:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('jsTxtArea');
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea , {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: 'javascript'
});

// set the value
myCodeMirror.setValue('Some Code');
```